# Dropdown in Magento-2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to set **Qty** Dropdown in **minicart** in magento2.

If any one knows please explain me?

Comment: so what should be the limit you want to set?

Comment: if($qty>4){while(i<=4)}

Comment: else {while(i==$qty)

Comment: if u have any idea  please explain me .i'm spend lot of time in that

Comment: In order to set dropdown for quantity, you have to override the phtml from the location   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

Comment: I dont think you can get product stock quantity from the way illustrated in the above link.

Comment: to get an idea about product stock quantity , refer the link  https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-product-stock-information-magento-2.html

Comment: Any idea  ........